# Not able to display content in mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I have added a lightbox to a webpage, but the content doesn't show up in mobile view. I am a developer and new to designing.

http://www.kahui.org/user/boardmember

Comment: You're more likely to get help on here if you share your code and say what you've tried already.

Comment: Thnx @GregPrisament, I would have shared the code but I am not sure which part of code I need to share, I mean I am still confused is it a CSS issue or the HTML issue.

Comment: @WASI, please paste the code for your lightbox and associated css tags. that might help. Or you could create a sample on jsfiddle using skeleton tags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the styles.css:2362

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    ...
    .about-left p:nth-child(3) {
        display: none;
    }
    ...
}
```

It says browser to hide `<p>` if it's the third child.